# Jquery reload php value from .txt file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to reload some data from .txt files.

The .txt files looks like this:
    0;Player 1;10;Player 2;10;Player 3;0;Player 4;0;00:00:00;0;0

I tryed to reload the data `"10"` after Player 1 which had the PHP Value `$s1s[2]`.

Following Code does read the whole txt file (I know), but I am not familiar with Javascript and I need to get the output of this single Value instead of the whole txt file.

PHP:

```
$spielfile = "data/$v/source.txt";
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
    $("<?php echo "#staende_$v" ?>").load("<?php print $spielfile ?>");
  }, 1000);
});
```

Any suggestion how I can do this?

Comment: Is it possible to change the format of the text file? If you use JSON this will be much, *much* more simple. Your logic is flawed here as your code does not re-load the text file every second, it just gets the data as it was when the page loaded. To do that I'd suggest using websockets as making an AJAX request to your server every second is the same as DDOSing yourself.

Comment: Hello @RoryMcCrossan

Thanks for your answer.

It´s not possible to change the format. This running only on an local system. The request time will be changed when all is running smooth.

I can not follow you what you mean with "it just gets the data as it was when the page loaded"

When i change the data of the .txt it will automatically reloaded.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could search the string using a regex:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $.get(
      "<?= $spielfile ?>",
      { "_": $.now() }, // disable response cache, multiple methods available.
      function(data) {

        var val = data.replace(/.*;Player 1;([0-9]+).*/, '$1');
        $("#staende_<?= $v ?>").text(val);
      }
    );
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks - This worked like a charm!!!

I have to check the code and delete }) after  $("#staende_<?php $v ?>").text(val);

Comment: It is unwise to A: Request a response where only 2% if the data is used (overhead) (especially on a refresh rate of 1 second). B: Letting the client do useless calculations that the server should have filtered out in the first place. Also `<?php $v ?>` isn't doing anything.

Comment: replace it with `<?= $v ?>`

Comment: Thanks!

I changed it to <?= $v ?>!

A: For this time i am only looking how to get work with this data. In runtime i will reload 95% of the data and setting the refresh rate to 30 - 60 seconds.)

So my next step is to learn how i do a foreach with your script.

Also i will check out Rorys Script later.

Comment: Sry i meaned @Xorifelse Script!! Thanks both for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As [Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822803/jquery-reload-php-value-from-txt-file#comment76625680_44822803) mentions, you should be using an Ajax request returning data in JSON.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $.get(
      "yourscript.php",
      { "_": $.now() }, // disable response cache, multiple methods available.
      function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(player){
          $('<?= "#staende_$v" ?>').text("Player: " + player.id + " has data " + player.data);
        })
      }
    );
  }, 1000);
});
```

Your PHP should obviously load the text file, fetch the desired data and return in correct format:

```
<?php
  $content = file_get_contents('./source.txt');
  $content = explode(';', $content);

  // The array should look like this for the js to function:
  $data[] = [
    'id' => 1,
    'data' => $content[2]
  ];

  // You can append more data for other players as well, easy to loop through in JS.
  die(json_encode($data)); 
?>
```

There was also a little problem with browser cache, the second param in the `$.get` request would resolve that. You can do `"<?= $spielfile ?>?time="+$.now()` instead of using the second param.